# Почему sql запрос неверен?

Tags: sql, sqlite

подскажите пожалуйста почему запрос неверен?

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('visa.db')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            if cursor:
                cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visa_users_family_2 (member text, phone_code text, number text, email text, appoinment_date text, firstname text,lastname text, date_of_birth text, passport_issue_date text, passport_expiry_date text, passport_issue_place text,passport_number text,visa_type text,nationality text,type_passport text,firstname2 text,lastname2 text, date_of_birth2 text, passport_issue_date2 text, passport_expiry_date2 text, passport_issue_place2 text,passport_number2 text,visa_type2 text,nationality2 text,type_passport2 text')
```

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visa_users_family_2 (member text, phone_code text, number text, email text, appoinment_date text, firstname text,lastname text, date_of_birth text, passport_issue_date text, passport_expiry_date text, passport_issue_place text,passport_number text,visa_type text,nationality text,type_passport text,firstname2 text,lastname2 text, date_of_birth2 text, passport_issue_date2 text, passport_expiry_date2 text, passport_issue_place2 text,passport_number2 text,visa_type2 text,nationality2 text,type_passport2 text')
sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропущена скобка внутри запроса (на что, собсно, и намекает incomplete input).

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visa_users_family_2 (member text, phone_code text, number text, email text, appoinment_date text, firstname text,lastname text, date_of_birth text, passport_issue_date text, passport_expiry_date text, passport_issue_place text,passport_number text,visa_type text,nationality text,type_passport text,firstname2 text,lastname2 text, date_of_birth2 text, passport_issue_date2 text, passport_expiry_date2 text, passport_issue_place2 text,passport_number2 text,visa_type2 text,nationality2 text,type_passport2 text)')
```

*А вообще, когда есть текст ошибки, гораздо проще загуглить, чем писать вопросы на СО.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь